# RAD 6.1 + System Properties for all projects

Tags: java, ibm-rad

I'm attempting to find how can I set a bunch of properties that could be accessed for any project. Let's say, that from any .java, I can do something like:

```
String var = System.getProperty(VAR_I_WANT);
```

Is it possible? I've found it for just one project, but I would like to do it for all, since all of them use it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this to set them as environment variables outside of RAD (do this before launching RAD) either by changing them in the shell (or Advanced System Settings in Windows) or by establishing them in a script you use to launch RAD (or Eclipse or RSA).  The latter is what we did at work to establish all of our common environment variables.  This was the set-up we used for all of the 60+ developers that used RSA.

Another, less recommended, approach is to edit the JRE definition (Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs) so that it has the System properties defined as VM arguments.  For example, you would include `-DVAR_I_WANT=myValue -DNEXT_VAR_I_WANT=myValue2` and so on.  You have to be careful here that you don't use this VM for projects that should not have those variables defined.  The easiest way around this would be to duplicate the JRE definition, change the copy, then use the new JRE in all of your projects.

Comment: I tried the Script option with a Batch file but how do you set the parameters so they can be used from RAD? Is it like -Dtest="true"?

Comment: For the batch/script file option, they should be defined like any other environment variable.  In Windows `export VAR_I_WANT="myValue"` in the .bat file.  In bash, `export VAR_I_WANT="myValue"`.  The end of this script should start RAD/eclipse/RSA (they are all eclipse variants).  If I remember RAD correctly, the command you execute is itself a script that just invokes eclipse with a given parameter to load the RAD plugins.  You can either invoke this script from your script or you can copy the contents into your batch file.